# Oracle - allowing the LIKE clause being configured by another select

Tags: sql, oracle

In a script I'm running the following query on an Oracle database:

```
select nvl(max(to_char(DATA.VALUE)), 'OK') 
from DATA 
where DATA.FILTER like (select DATA2.FILTER from DATA2 where DATA2.FILTER2 = 'WYZ')
```

In the actual script it's a bit more complicated, but you get the idea. ;-)

DATA2.FILTER contains the filter which needs to applied on DATA as a LIKE -clause. The idea is to have it as generic as possible, meaning it should be possible to filter on:

- FILTER%
- %FILTER
- FI%LTER
- %FILTER%
- FILTER             (as if the clause was DATA.FILTER = (select DATA2.FILTER from DATA2 where DATA2.FILTER2 = 'WYZ')

The system the script runs on does not allow stored procedures to run for this kind of task, also I can't make the scrip build the query directly before running it.

Whatever data needs to be fetched, it has to be done with one single query.

I've already tried numerous solutions I found online, but no matter what I do, I seem to be misisng the mark.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?

Comment: I only get results when the query returns the actual value I'm lookinh for... I can't get it to work with wildcards.

Comment: It [worked for me in a test that I did](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfa4b/6/0). What values are you using that aren't working?

Comment: Well I passed FILTER% directly as a string...

Comment: If you can modify the SQLFiddle that I created to show the problem, I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This one?

```
select nvl(max(to_char(DATA.VALUE)), 'OK') 
from DATA 
   JOIN DATA2 on DATA.FILTER LIKE DATA2.FILTER 
where DATA2.FILTER2 = 'WYZ'
```

Note: The performance of this query is not optimal, because for table DATA Oracle will perform always a "Full Table Scan" - but it works.

Comment: Performance is an issue.... I'll try this one, but at least one of the tables I have to join by default is huge